# Reading the file only once for every method call

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

I am new to object-oriented programming and I am working on a small personal project with some SQL scripts.

I have a scenario where a SQL script calls a static method with a file path as input.

```
queries = Select Query from Table where Utils.ContainsKeyword(Query, @Path1) AND NOT Utils.ContainsKeyword(Query, @Path2);
```

I had initially created a static class that does the following:

```
public static class Utils
{
   public static bool ContainsKeyword(string query, string path)
   {
      var isQueryInFile = false;
      var stringFromFile = GetStringFromFile(path);
      List<Regex>regexList = GetRegexList(stringFromFile);
      if(regexList!= null)
      {
        isQueryInFile = regexList.Any(pattern => pattern.IsMatch(query));
      }
      return isQueryInFile;
   }
   
   private static string GetStringFromFile(string path)
   {
     var words = String.Empty;
     if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
     {
       try
       {
         using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path))
         {
           words = sr.ReadToEnd().Replace(Environment.Newline, "");
         }
       }
       catch { return words; }
     }
     return words;
   }

  private static List<Regex> GetRegexList(string words)
  {
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(words)) { return null; }
    return words.Split(',').Select(w=> new Regex(@"\b" + Regex.Escape(w) + @'\b', RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)).ToList();
  }
}
```

My problem is that I neither want to read from the file every time the ContainsKeyword static method is called nor do I want to create a new RegexList every time. *Also, I cannot change the SQL script and I have to send the path to the file as an input parameter for the method call in the SQL script since the path might change in the future.*

**Is there a way to make sure I only read the contents from the input path only once, store them in a string, and use the string for the match with different input queries?**

Comment: Your GetStringFromFile is essentially a repetition of the baked-into-the-framework method `File.ReadAllText`

Comment: *Is there a way to make sure I only read the contents from the input path only once* - yes, but is it really causing a problem? Better that files live on disk than in memory. If you start caching it then you need to handle expiry/rereads if the file changes, plus what to do if multiple different paths are sent (you can end up caching a lot of data). If it's not causing a demonstrable perf problem I'd leave it alone.

Comment: @CaiusJard yes, there are performance issues. That SQL script reads data from a huge data stream with over 100 million rows. I don't want to read the file every time or create the regex every time I read a query from the data stream.

Comment: Are your regexes literally just "contains word x, ignore case"? That doesn't need Regex:

Comment: When you say "I have a sql script that calls a static method, do you mean you have loaded this C# into SQL Server and invoke it from there? Ultimately your goal is to pull all rows from a table where some column has a word that is present in file1 and not present in file2? Tell us more about the files - why aren't they just tables in the database?

Answer (score 0):

To read the content only once, saving in memory will probaby be needed. Memory capacity could be an issue.

```
public Dictionary<string, string> FileContentCache { get; set; } // make sure that gets initialized


public string GetFileContentCache(string path)
{
    if (FileContentCache == null) FileContentCache = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    if (FileContentCache.ContainsKey(path))
        return FileContentCache[path];
        
    var fileData = GetStringFromFile(path);
    FileContentCache.Add(path, fileData);
    return fileData;
}
```

Comment: I did wonder about a dictionary with the path as they key, but given _" have to send the path to the file as an input parameter for the method call in the SQL script **since the path might change in the future**"_ I thought it probably wouldn't be necessary. And certainly doesn't suggest memory usage would be a problem - but this would work. Notes: does `FileContentCache` need to be a public property rather than a private field in this scenario, and why not just initialise it with `= new(Dictionary<string, string>())` in the declaration?

Comment: This doesn't solve the second part though - _nor do I want to create a new RegexList every time_..